# .ics files not opening in Chrome Mobile for Apple Devices

Tags: c#, google-chrome, mobile, icalendar

I'm getting an Error 102 (): Unknown File Type. when trying to download an .ics file from an ASP.Net application. The file looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART:20130506T173000
DTEND:20130506T190000
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: What would you do with an extra $2500? 
SUMMARY:Smoking Cessation May
PRIORITY:0
LOCATION:ARMC Theater
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

My Response code in C# is this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.ics", "example"));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(calendarData.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I don't remember, I am no longer with this company and forgot what happened, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Everything I've read says it's not possible through Chrome Mobile.  If you find an answer, I'd be interested as well.

If it's any help, I know it's possible through Safari Mobile.  The answer is here:

[How do you add a link that will add an event to your iPhone calendar from safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168440/how-do-you-add-a-link-that-will-add-an-event-to-your-iphone-calendar-from-safari)

With Safari Mobile, the solution is simply to link to the .ics file, but this wasn't even possible with Safari Mobile until iOS 5.

Sorry, and best of luck!